# Как реализовать кликабельную метку поверх QPixmap

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Я в тупике, не знаю как реализовать задуманное. У меня в QLable лежит QPixmap. Это дело представляет собой карту. На карту пользователь должен кликами(и не только) наносить метки. Это может быть круглая жирная точка, или может быть какая-нибудь векторная маленькая картинка. Метки можно, как добавлять на карту в нужные места, так и удалять с нее. В идеале, это должно представлять из себя хоть какой-нибудь объект, а не просто перерисовка QPixmap, т.к. надо запихнуть в эту метку информацию(Хотя бы айдишник этой метки). Метка(уже после установки на карту) должна быть чувствительна к кликам на нее для вывода формы(если клик ЛКМ) и диалога удаления(если клик ПКМ). Кроме того, размер метки должен пропорционально изменяться относительно размеров окна. Поэтому я и подумал про векторную картинку, но все равно так и не понял, как ее применить. Еще подумывал, про QPainter, но он просто перерисовывает QPixmap, я не смогу превратить это в полноценный кликабельный объект с которым мог бы взаимодействовать пользователь. Может можно как-то по нужным координатам QLable расположить перерисованный QPushButton? Т.е. как-то превратить продолговатую кнопку в маленькую круглую красную, например. Но и это не представляю как проделать. Может кто-нибудь сможет что-то подсказать или направить мысли в нужное русло.
Для работы программы у меня уже все реализовано кроме самих меток.

Comment: Вам нужны `QGraphicsScene` и `QGraphicsView`. Это связка сцены (т. е. коллекции) и её графического отображения, которая позволяет размещать множество графических элементов сразу, позволяя взаимодействовать с некоторыми из них мышью и/или клавиатурой.

Comment: У меня возникли трудности при переходе с QLabel на QGraphicsView, потому пока придется отложить реализацию меток. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/908818/311899

Comment: Вариант с QGraphicsView для меня не работает из-за того, что корежит изображение, да и само по себе как-то коряво работает. Я даже попытался внутрь сцены запихнуть QLabel с QPixmap, но изображение все равно корежит, видимо, из-за использования QGraphicsView. Есть ли иное решение для меток с использованием QLabel и без использования QGraphicsScene и QGraphicsView? Хоть какая-нибудь лазейка...

Comment: В общем, отнаследовался от QWidget и в методе paintEvent() реализовал рисование метки через QPainter.