# Нужен полный аналог setScaledContents(true), как у QLabel, но только для QGraphicsView

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Мне пришлось переписать связку QLabel-QPixmap на связку QGraphicsView-QGraphicsScene-QGraphicsPixmapItem-QPixmap. И вышло как-то совсем не очень.

Раньше было так:

```
void MainWindow::slotConstructWaterBodies(const QString& mapName, const QString& mapImagePath)
{   
    ui->mylabel->setPixmap(mapImagePath);
    /*Прочий код*/
}

void MainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    adjustWidgetSize();    
    QMainWindow::resizeEvent(event);
}
```

Задает фиксированный размер виджета по ширине для сохранения пропорций картинки внутри него:

```
void MainWindow::adjustWidgetSize()
{
    int widthCurrentPixMap = 1;
    int heightCurrentPixMap = 1;

    if(pixPtr_) {
        widthCurrentPixMap = pixPtr_->width();
        heightCurrentPixMap = pixPtr_->height();
    }

    const QSize pixmapSize(widthCurrentPixMap, heightCurrentPixMap);

    ui->mylabel->setFixedWidth(
        ui->centralWidget->height() * pixmapSize.width() / pixmapSize.height()
    );
}
```

Ну там еще конечно самое важное в самом дизайнере - чек бокс напротив ScaledContents.

Теперь же все усложняется, ибо никакого ScaledContents свойства у QGraphicsView, к огромному сожалению, не имеется :

```
void MainWindow::slotConstructWaterBodies(const QString& mapName, const QString& mapImagePath)
{   
    QPixmap *pixmap = new QPixmap(mapImagePath);
    pixPtr_ = pixmap;

    QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene;
    QGraphicsPixmapItem *item = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(*pixPtr_);
    item->setTransformationMode(Qt::SmoothTransformation);
    scene->addItem(item);
    ui->graphicsViewMap->setScene(scene);
    ui->graphicsViewMap->fitInView(scene->sceneRect(), Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio);

    /*Прочий код*/
}

void MainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    adjustWidgetSize();    
    adjustScaledPixmap();

    QMainWindow::resizeEvent(event);
}
```

Задает фиксированный размер виджета по ширине для сохранения пропорций картинки внутри него:

```
void MainWindow::adjustWidgetSize()
{
    int widthCurrentPixMap = 1;
    int heightCurrentPixMap = 1;

    if(pixPtr_) {
        widthCurrentPixMap = pixPtr_->width();
        heightCurrentPixMap = pixPtr_->height();
    }
    const QSize pixmapSize(widthCurrentPixMap, heightCurrentPixMap);

    ui->graphicsViewMap->setFixedWidth(
        ui->centralWidget->height() * pixmapSize.width() / pixmapSize.height()
    );
}

void MainWindow::adjustScaledPixmap()
{
    QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene;

    QGraphicsPixmapItem *item = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(*pixPtr_);
    item->setTransformationMode(Qt::SmoothTransformation);
    scene->addItem(item);
    ui->graphicsViewMap->setScene(scene);
    ui->graphicsViewMap->fitInView(scene->sceneRect(), Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio);
}
```

Но при этом сильно шершавит изображение до такой степени, что текст на нем становится еле читабельным. Никакие Qt::SmoothTransformation совершенно не помогают. Да еще и scale по каким-то причинам более-менее нормально отрабатывает лишь когда срабатывает resizeEvent, т.е. при первом запуске окна, если оно не на весь экран (когда на весь экран, то почему-то срабатывает - а на весь или не на весь это зависит от чтения из QSettings), то изображение почему-то очень мелкое по центру почти пустого виджета.

Еще, между изображением и виджетом QGraphicsView появляется белая мелкая рамка и она может становится больше в зависимости от размера открытого окна.

Ну и кроме того, мне теперь приходится хранить в классе указатель на динамически созданный QPixmap, т.к. QGraphicsPixmapItem зачем-то требует текущий pixmap, а ui->graphicsViewMap->grab() его не устраивает.

Можно как-то получить результат в стиле QLabel?

Comment: По поводу отсутствия сглаживания: добавьте `ui->graphicsViewMap->view.setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing | QPainter::HighQualityAntialiasing | QPainter::TextAntialiasing | QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform);`. Думаю, эту строку стоит разместить ещё до задания сцены.

Comment: Эффекта нет. Я еще в дизайнере раньше пробовал выставлять чекбоксы на эти поля, но они совершенно не помогали. Потом мне порекомендовали использовать QGraphicsPixmapitem->setTransformationMode(Qt::SmoothTransformation) - с этим хоть как-то становится лучше, но вовсе недостаточно

Comment: Сглаживание не включается даже при отметке всех галочек в свойстве `renderHints` у вида? Странно. [Бросил клич в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47680971#47680971), может, кто-нибудь укажет, в чём проблема.

Comment: Да, проставлял все галочки у qgraphicsView в дизайнере в блоке renderHints  - вообще без какого-либо эффекта. Кодом такой же результат.

Comment: У вас какая операционная система и версия Qt?

Comment: И ещё, откройте в Qt Creator на левой панели раздел *Projects* (*Проекты*), и на вкладке *Run* (*Запуск*) в поле *Command line arguments* (*Параметры командной строки*) напишите `-graphicssystem raster`, после чего запустите вашу программу в режиме отладки (все указанные мной выше флаги вида должны быть установлены в форме или коде). Дело в том, что после перехода Qt GUI на OpenGL в пятой версии начали наблюдаться разнообразные ошибки, а указанный мной флаг временно возвращает старую подсистему отрисовки.

Comment: У меня Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon, Qt 5.11.2, creator 4.7.2. -graphicssystem raster прописал в аргументы, провалился в точку останова, затем continue - никаких изменений не заметил. Есть еще такой момент - мне в app out при запуске уже довольно давно выдает QApplication: invalid style override passed, ignoring it. Это появилось после какой-то очередной версии linux mint, но думаю, что это не имеет отношения к делу. А ведь когда я скалирую через qlabel таких проблем не наблюдается, а там наверняка в кишках qt эти же самые параметры(renderHints) где-нибудь прописаны уже.